# What is approximate vector solution for least squares solution?

Tags: linear-algebra, least-squares

For this question, I understand that first I have to form matrix A and b for Ax=b. Then, Part (i) is using ⃗ = which is the normal equation to solve for x.

I tried to search on what exactly "approximate vector solution" is for (ii), but I can't seem to find any results. I have an intuition it is related to projecting the b vector onto a plane to find ˆb (b hat) , can someone advice further on what is the approach to (ii)? Thank you!

**Question:**

[image]